# In a test, how to pass default request parameters to get/post/put/delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Consider this example:

```
describe UsersController do
  it "works for something" do
    # some other code
    get :show, {facebook_id: 1000000000}
    # some other code
    put :update, {facebook_id: 1000000000, birthday: "2001-01-01"}
    # some other code
    get :show, {facebook_id: 1000000000}
    # some other code
  end

  it "works for another thing" do
    # some other code
    get :show, {facebook_id: 1000000000}
    # some other code
  end
end
```

How to DRY out the `{facebook_id: 1000000000}` so that I can simple write `get :show`, `put :update, {birthday: "2001-01-01"}`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
def options(*args)
  _options = args.extract_options!
  _options.merge({facebook_id: 1000000000})
end
```

then

```
get :show, options
put :update, options(birthday: "2001-01-01")
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your controller do with that facebook_id? I would stub the method that requires that facebook_id when you are not testing that, something like what I suggested here [RSpec Request - How to set http authorization header for all requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761544/rspec-request-how-to-set-http-authorization-header-for-all-requests)